# How to refocus on a Jframe every few seconds?

Tags: focus, jframe, jpanel

This code brings up a Jframe with my 'Paneltest' jpanel inside.

Panel test has a text field and button that launches a webpage with whatever is in the text field at the end of the URL, I.E. (www.website.com/textfield)

When the webpage is launched it pulls focus off the jframe, the ways I have tried to refocus it so far have not worked.

```
          JFrame f = new JFrame("KioskApp");
          f.setSize(800, 600);

          Paneltest Paneltest = new Paneltest();

          f.add(Paneltest);

          f.setVisible(true)
```

I tried surrounding this code with a while statement and adding f.dispose and Thread.sleep(x) to the end to get it to close the frame and bring it up again after a few seconds but It caused Paneltest to not show up in the frame.

Anytime I added a while loop it stopped Paneltest from showing up so I couldn't test other methods like f.toFront or f.requestfocus.

What do I add to have it perpetually refocus or relaunch the Jframe correctly.

Edit: This is now where I am at.

If I add the code suggested by マルちゃん だよ  Then all that happens is the tab for the frame highlights in the taskbar.

**Bringtofront**

```
package kioskapp;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author jorent
 */
public class BringToFront {
  JFrame frame;   
  Timer timer;


  public BringToFront(JFrame frame) {
this.frame = frame;
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new ToFrontTask(), 5000);
}
   class ToFrontTask extends TimerTask {

  @Override
  public void run() {
   frame.toFront();
   frame.repaint();

}
  }
}
```

Here is a snippet from the code where I implement the Jframe that needs to refocus

**InitialSetupPane**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    JFrame f1 = new JFrame("KioskApp");//initializes frame to open the panel
          f1.setSize(650, 400);// Functionless setting of the size, I used it to approximate the size of the destination screen

          Paneltest Paneltest = new Paneltest();//initializes Panel to be put in the fram

           f1.add(Paneltest);// puts the panel in the fram

           f1.setUndecorated(true);// Removes the ability to mess with the screen

           f1.setVisible(true);//makes the frame visible

           f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);// When not fullscreen(not a possibility now) changes the (X) button to close instead of hide the frame

           f1.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);// Fullsc       

           new BringToFront (f1);


}
```

If I add .alwaysontop to bring to the front it will work but I doesnt let me type anything into the frame's text field with out clicking the window(clicking will be disabled for the end-user, so that will not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fire the `.toFront()` / `.requestFocus()` from a different thread or from a timer.

Example using thread:

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run() {
       while(true) {
           f.requestFocus(); // or f.toFront()
           Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second
       }
    }
}.start();
```

Example using timer:

```
public class BringToFront {
  JFrame frame;   
  Timer timer;

  public BringToFront(JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new ToFrontTask (), 1000); // 1 second intervals
  }

  class ToFrontTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       frame.toFront();
       frame.repaint();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("KioskApp");
      f.setSize(800, 600);
      Paneltest Paneltest = new Paneltest();
      f.add(Paneltest);
      f.setVisible(true)
      new BringToFront(f);
  }
}
```

In the timer example I encapsulate the JFrame reference so it can be called by the timer method, you can do the same for the Thread one.

Edit: for usign invokeLater with a Timer you can place the code inside the `run()` method of the timer callback:

```
...

class ToFrontTask extends TimerTask {
   public void run() {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               myFrame.toFront();
               myFrame.repaint();
           }
       });
   }
}

...
```

Comment: This makes it so that the frame is highlighted in the task bar but doesn't bring it to the front. I looked at the link you supplied(The problem they had is exactly this) but how do I use .invokelater and timer together?